# ASP.NET MVC 5 not getting all items in bound checkbox when skiping one item

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

When binding checkboxes if I use at for next loop and I skip one item it does not bind all the items.

Here is my code:

Model:

```
 public class UserViewModel
 {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public IList<Meal> Meals { get; set; }
 }

 public class Meal
 {
        public string MealId { get; set; }
        public string MealName { get; set; }
        public bool HasMeal { get; set; }
 }
```

Razor:

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
</div>



@*Meals CheckBoxes*@
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Meals.Count(); i++)
{
    if (Model.Meals[i].MealsName == "JunkFood")
    {
        continue;
    }

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label(Model.Meals[i].MealName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })

        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Meals[i].HasMeal)
            </div>
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Meals[i].MealId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Meals[i].MealName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Meals[i].HasMeal)
    </div>
}
```

In the html I get a discontinued itemId as expected...

```
<input name="Roles[0].HasMeals" type="hidden" value="false">
<input name="Roles[1].HasMeals" type="hidden" value="false">
<input name="Roles[2].HasMeals" type="hidden" value="false">
<input name="Roles[3].HasMeals" type="hidden" value="false">
<input name="Roles[5].HasMeals" type="hidden" value="false">
```

same with the other controls

```
<input class="check-box" data-val="true" id="<Meals_3__HasRole" name="Meals[3].HasRole" type="checkbox" value="true">

<input class="check-box" data-val="true" id="<Meals_5__HasRolenter code here" name="Meals[5].HasRole" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

Then in the controller I just get 4 items instead of 5.

If I take out the continue statement in the for next loop everything works but it shows the junkFood checkbox which I want to hide...

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Email, Meals")] UserViewModel userViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
          ....
```

UserViewModel.Meals.Count is 4

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that if you skip the whole iteration for MealsName == "JunkFood", the view won't generate the necessary input names for the entire collection.
Do this instead:

```
@*Meals CheckBoxes*@
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Meals.Count(); i++)
{
    // Generate user interface only for valid meals
    if (Model.Meals[i].MealsName != "JunkFood")
    {

        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label(Model.Meals[i].MealName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })

        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Meals[i].HasMeal)
            </div>
        </div>
    }   
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Meals[i].MealId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Meals[i].MealName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Meals[i].HasMeal)
    </div>
}
```

Will result in:

```
<input name="Roles[0].HasMeals" type="hidden" value="false">
<input name="Roles[1].HasMeals" type="hidden" value="false">
<input name="Roles[2].HasMeals" type="hidden" value="false">
<input name="Roles[3].HasMeals" type="hidden" value="false">
<input name="Roles[4].HasMeals" type="hidden" value="false">
<input name="Roles[5].HasMeals" type="hidden" value="false">
```

but only:

```
<input class="check-box" data-val="true" id="Meals_0__HasMeals" name="Meals[0].HasMeals" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input class="check-box" data-val="true" id="Meals_1__HasMeals" name="Meals[1].HasMeals" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input class="check-box" data-val="true" id="Meals_2__HasMeals" name="Meals[2].HasMeals" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input class="check-box" data-val="true" id="Meals_3__HasMeals" name="Meals[3].HasMeals" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input class="check-box" data-val="true" id="Meals_5__HasMeals" name="Meals[5].HasMeals" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

When hitting submit button, your Controller will receive 6 values, but [4] will always be false, since there isn't any checkbox which can override the hidden input value.

This way it should work as you expect, I think.